# In which sense is cohomology dual to homology?

Tags: algebraic-topology, soft-question, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Colimits in a category $C$ are called "**co**limits" because they are limits in the dual category $C^\mathrm{op}$.

**Question:** Why is singular cohomology called "**co**homology"? In which way does it arise from singular homology by "dualizing" it? It is not as simple as in the example above: I don't know what $C$ is in this case.

Comment: The arrows go in the other direction.  But the answer would greatly depend on what flavor of co/homology you're asking about.

Comment: The opposite category of an abelian category $\mathcal A$ is also abelian. Homology of a right exact functor $\mathcal A\to\mathcal B$ and cohomology of the left exact functor $\mathcal A^{op}\to\mathcal B^{op}$ are the same thing.

Comment: Singular, as I say. :)

Comment: @Randall Which arrows go in the other direction? Which category are you talking about?

Comment: Cohomology is contravariant.

Comment: @Randall Which arrows go in the other direction? Which category are you talking about?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As noted in comments you work with singular (co)homology.

Both homology and cohomology arise by considering the singular chain complex first:

$$\cdots \xrightarrow{} C_{i+1} \xrightarrow{\partial_{i+1}} C_{i}\xrightarrow{\partial_{i}} C_{i-1}\xrightarrow{}\cdots$$

At this point homology is defined as $H_i(X):=\text{ker }\partial_i/\text{im }\partial_{i+1}$. Then it can be shown that $H_i$ is functorial in a covariant manner, i.e. a continuous function $f:X\to Y$ is converted to $H_i(f):H_i(X)\to H_i(Y)$ homomorphism.

With cohomology we add one more step. We take an abelian group $A$ and convert our original singular chain complex by applying $\text{Hom}(\cdot,A)$ to it. Since $\text{Hom}$ is contravariant (it reverses arrows), this gives us

$$\cdots \xleftarrow{} C^{i+1} \xleftarrow{\partial^{i+1}} C^{i}\xleftarrow{\partial^{i}} C^{i-1}\xleftarrow{}\cdots$$

where $C^i=\text{Hom}(C_i, A)$ and $\partial^i=\text{Hom}(\partial_i,A)$. This is called singular cochain complex. Then similarly we define $H^i(X,A):=\text{ker }\partial^{i+1}/\text{im }\partial^{i}$ (note that indexes are reversed). The fact that arrows are reversed during the construction of cochain complex translates to functoriality of $H^i$: it becomes contravariant, meaning a continuous function $f:X\to Y$ is mapped to $H^i(f,A):=H^i(Y,A)\to H^i(X,B)$ homomorphism (note that $X$ and $Y$ switched places).

That's where **co** comes from. It has more to do with the fact that cohomology is contravariant, rather then any duality relationship.

---

Note that there's a variant of homology called "homology with coefficients". We construct it by adding one more step. Similarly to cohomology, we take an abelian group $A$ but instead of applying $\text{Hom}(\cdot, A)$ we apply the tensor product $\cdot\otimes A$ to the chain complex. The tensor product is covariant, so no arrow gets inverted, and the resulting homology is denoted by $H_i(X,A)$. For $A=\mathbb{Z}$ it coincides with the usual definition.

I mention this because you asked in what sense homology is dual to cohomology? Well, it is not. They are however closely related by the so called [universal coefficient theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_coefficient_theorem). In the specific case when $k$ is a field, this theorem implies that

$$H^n(X,k)\simeq \text{Hom}_k(H_n(X,k), k)$$

(because $\text{Ext}^1$ vanishes over fields) which means that cohomology is the dual space of homology. However for non-fields this is no longer true, and the universal coefficient theorem precisely states how they are related (in a somewhat ugly way).

All in all: generally cohomology is not dual to homology in any reasonable way. However they are closely related.

Comment: Very nice answer +1